# Python max heap of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

The suggested method to have a max heap is to multiply the key with -1.
What is the suggested method to have a max heap of strings?

Is there an alternative library that has that feature?

Comment: The python standard library provides [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html)

Comment: Yes but that is min heap. I want the inverse.

Comment: I think this question is very reasonable as current heapq library does not support 'max heap' by some parameter. upvote!

Answer (score 6):

Create your own custom string class:

```
class MyString:
    def __init__(self, word):
        self.word = word

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.word > other.word

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.word == other.word
```

And use it like:

```
heapq.heappush(heap, MyString(word))
```

Comment: This should be a generic Reverse class, that's how [Rust does it](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/struct.Reverse.html).

Answer (score 4):

You could construct a maxheap from your strings by using `heapq` to build a minheap of string-like objects whose character content is the same as your original strings but whose comparison operators (and therefore their sort order) produce results that are the opposite of the normal string object.  If we call that object a `contra_string` then it would be defined like this:

```
class contra_string(str):

    def __init__(self, s):
       self.original = s

    def __lt__(self, s):
        return self.original.__gt__(s)

    def __le__(self, s):
        return self.original.__ge__(s)

    def __eq__(self, s):
        return self.original.__eq__(s)

    def __ne__(self, s):
        return self.original.__ne__(s)

    def __gt__(self, s):
        return self.original.__lt__(s)

    def __ge__(self, s):
        return self.original.__le__(s)

    def normal(self):
        return self.original
```

It would be used like this:

```
import heapq

mystrings = [ 'b', 'c', 'a', 'bravo', 'alpha', 'charlie' ]

maxheap = [contra_string(s) for s in mystrings]
heapq.heapify(maxheap)

print [heapq.heappop(maxheap) for n in range(len(maxheap))]
# prints "['charlie', 'c', 'bravo', 'b', 'alpha', 'a']"
```

Bear in mind that the objects in the heap are instances of `contra_string`, so they'll behave strangely if you use them in comparisons after you pop them from the heap.  If you need to do anything involving naturally-ordered string comparisons with those objects after extracting them then you can recover the original ordinary string by using the `normal` method on the `contra_string`, and of course comparisons using those original strings will behave normally.  That would look like:

```
original_strings_in_reverse_order = [heapq.heappop(maxheap).normal() for n in range(len(maxheap))]
print type(original_strings_in_reverse_order[0])
# prints "<type 'str'>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to post a shorter version of [@me_astr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60576287/6854489) using the same technique of a custom class. In this case, I just extended the str class and overrode the `__lt__` method used by the heapq class to invert it:

```py
class ContraStr(str):
    def __lt__(self, s):
        return self.__gt__(s)

str_heap: list[ContraStr] = []
for word in ['c', 'aa', 'b', 'd', 'a']:
    heapq.heappush(str_heap, ContraStr(word))
print(str_heap)
```

The above prints out:

```
['d', 'c', 'b', 'aa', 'a']
```

Note that like [@ottomeister said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59013954/6854489), you have to be careful with using these `ContraStr` objects later since the comparisons will be backwards. For example, if you want a normally-sorted list from the heap, you'll need to sort in reverse.

```py
print(sorted(str_heap, reverse=True))

# prints ['a', 'aa', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

Invert the string by making character values negative? Example key for a fully lowercase string:

```
lambda s: ''.join(chr(ord('z') - ord(c) + ord('a')) for c in s)
```

Comment: What if s1 = "a" and s2 = "aa" ? You should consider the length also.